# AVR USART file not recognized in C

Tags: c, avr

I have the following test setup below. When I compile the code, I get the following error: The initUSART is not recognized, but I have included the file in the appropriate places. Did I miss out on anything?

```
AVR Development Stack
Get input main.c file...
Compile code and return elf file...
main.o: In function `main':
/Users/sebastianscharf/Documents/Hardware/AVR/main.c:14: undefined reference to `initUSART'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
avr-objcopy: 'main.elf': No such file

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega328 is 1E 95 14
         Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

**main file**

```
#include "config.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "USART.h"

int main(void) {

  char serialCharacter;

  // --- INITS --- //
  DDRB = 0xff;

  // Set up LED for output
  initUSART();
  return 0;
}
```

**USART.h**

```
/* These are defined for convenience */
#define   USART_HAS_DATA   bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0)
#define   USART_READY      bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0)

uint8_t receiveByte(void);

/* Takes the defined BAUD and F_CPU, calculates the bit-clock multiplier, and configures the hardware USART*/
void initUSART(void);
```

**USART.c**

```
#include "config.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>
#include "USART.h"

void initUSART(void) {
    // Requires BAUD
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;

    #if USE_2X
        UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);
    #else
        UCSR0A &= ~(1 << U2X0);
    #endif

    // Enable USART
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00); // 8 data bits, 1 stop bit
}
```

**bash file**

```
#!/bin/bash

source bashColors.sh

echo -e "${IGreen}AVR Development Stack${Reset}"

echo -e "${BIBlue}Get input main.c file...${Reset}"
avr-gcc -g -Os -mmcu=atmega328p -c main.c USART.c &&

echo -e "${BIBlue}Compile code and return elf file...${Reset}"
avr-gcc -g -mmcu=atmega328p -o main.elf main.o &&

echo -e "${BIBlue}Convert elf file to hex...${Reset}"
# avr-objcopy converts into hex file. -j indicates that we want the information from the .text and .data segment extracted.
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex main.elf out.hex &&

echo -e "${BIBlue}Uploading data to microcontroller...${Reset}"
avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328
```

Comment: you need to add usart object file: `avr-gcc -g -mmcu=atmega328p -o main.elf main.o USART.o &&`

Comment: You should add `set -e` near the top of your Bash file so your script actually stops when there is an error instead of proceeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compiled both source files properly to `.o` with:

```
avr-gcc -g -Os -mmcu=atmega328p -c main.c USART.c
```

Now the `main.o` file contains an external reference to `initUSART` (partly thanks to the `#include "USART.h"` directive which provides the proper prototype)

but this link line:

```
avr-gcc -g -mmcu=atmega328p -o main.elf main.o &&
```

only references `main.o`. You need to add `USART.o` so the symbol is resolved by the linker (the linker *doesn't care* about `.h` include files), like this:

```
avr-gcc -g -mmcu=atmega328p -o main.elf main.o USART.o &&
```

Comment: Wow.... I just wasted 30min of my life time not seeing this :) Thank you Jean-Francois! Very helpful.

Comment: yeah SO is slower in the week-ends but you can get lucky. Glad to be of help.